# rearranging cell content based on their position

Tags: excel, vba

All data in the column A, content in each cell separated by comma. The numbers are from 1 to 4 or 1 to 1 to 5.
I would like to create the column B from column A.
Content of A2 is "4,1,2,3". I have to generate the content of B2 in the following way:

1. Searching for the number 1 in A2, its position in the cell is 2 (the second number), so the 1st number in B2 is 2,
2. Then searcing for the number 2 in A2, its position is 3, so the 2nd number in B2 is 3,
3. and so on.
   The final result for B2 is: 2,3,4,1.

I am a bit confused with these arrays. I come across the Split and Join functions, so i wanted to use them. Thanks for any help in advance.
My trial as follows:

```
Sub convert()
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim Oldtxt
Dim Newtxt As Variant
Dim Newcontent As String
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
Oldtxt = Split(Cells(i, 1), ",")
For k = 1 To UBound(Oldtxt) + 1
For j = 1 To UBound(Oldtxt) + 1
If CInt(Oldtxt(k)) = j Then Newtxt(CInt(j)) = k
Next j
Next k
Newcontent = Join(Newtxt, ",")
Cells(i, 2) = Newcontent
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: „2,3,4,1” does not mean increasing order... I am not able to understand the logic to be applied to obtain what you show us. Please, try better explain the splitting logic. At least, edit your question and show us more cases. Maybe we can better deduce what algorithm to be applied...

Comment: Is each string only limited to the numbers 1-4 comma seperated?

Comment: Should we understand that the first digit will be the second existing and the rest to be in increasing order?

Comment: Ok, forget the increasing order. 
Lets consider row3. B3 and A3 cells. B3(1)=4, since "1" is at the 4th place in A3, B3(2)=1, since 2 is the 1st element in A3, the third element of B3 B3(3) = 3, since 3 is the 3rd element in A3, and finally B3(4) =2 since "4" is the 2nd element in A2.

Comment: What version of Excel are you working with?

Comment: A3(1)=2, so the B3(2) will be 1 ...if we would omit the row number if A(1)=2 ----> B(2)=1....we change the element number in the array and the value....

Comment: Now with Excel 2007, but sometimes with excel 2016. Does it depend on the version?

Comment: Please, test the function I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
Sub convert()
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Dim Oldtxt as String
Dim Newtxt() As Variant
Dim Newcontent As String
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Oldtxt = Split(Cells(i, 1), ",")
        ReDim Newtxt(UBound(Oldtxt))
        For k = 0 To UBound(Oldtxt)
            Newtxt(Oldtxt(k) - 1) = k + 1
        Next k
        Newcontent = Join(Newtxt, ",")
        Cells(i, 2) = Newcontent
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is simple and works.:-) It is very similar that i would like to create. I like this solution.

Comment: Nice :-) Friendly hint due to [MS Help](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement
): *"If you don't specify a data type ..., the variable is Variant by default."*. So the correct intended syntax would be `Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer`. Furthermore I'd prefer to declare these counting variables as `Long` data type, especially with regard to row countings which might be higher than the positive integer maximum size of 32,767. *Btw there's no speed or other disadvantage as VBA internally operates with `Long` anyway here.*

Comment: Thanks TM for the tip on declaring variables.  I thought that if I declared all variables in one line the type applied for all.  I updated the code and removed some variables that weren't needed

Comment: Hunga, I'm glad it helped!  I also liked to solution it felt tidy! :-P

Answer (score 3):

**Algorithm**

- Split numbers into two arrays
- Sort one of the arrays
- Determine the position of each value from the sorted array, in the unsorted array.
- Output those positions as a comma-separated string.

I used the `ArrayList` as it is easy to sort:

```
Option Explicit
Function order(S As String) As String
    Dim AL1 As Object, AL2 As Object
    Dim v, w, x
    Dim I As Long
    
v = Split(S, ",")

Set AL1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each w In v
    AL1.Add w
Next w

Set AL2 = AL1.Clone
AL2.Sort

ReDim x(UBound(v))
I = 0
For Each w In AL2
    x(I) = AL1.indexof(w, 0) + 1
    I = I + 1
Next w

order = Join(x, ",")

End Function
```

[image]

Note that the above routine is a UDF (user defined function) so the formula `=order(a2)` would be entered in each cell in column B.

If you prefer to run this as a macro, where your data is in Column A, you can use this macro to "call" the UDF.  We do this within a VBA array as it is much faster than repeated read/writes to/from the worksheet.

So your VBA module would have both the function and the sub.

```
Sub digitOrder()
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim I As Long, R As Range
    
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
With WS
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    vData = R
End With

For I = 2 To UBound(vData, 1)
    vData(I, 2) = order(CStr(vData(I, 1)))
Next I

With R
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vData
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Creative, I would say (Array List). Can you share some info on this variable naming convention?

Comment: @VBasic2008 I think I don't understand your question.  I name my variables based on something that makes sense to me.  eg `vData` is a **v**ariant that will hold the **Data**.  `WS` is a **W**ork**S**heet. etc.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - suppose you rather mean methods of the ArrayList (mscorlib.tlb); a nice overview can be found [here](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Arraylist_en.html) :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Approach with without loops in main function**

The example call

- `[1]` assigns data strings to a variant array,
- `[2]` transforms items to the wanted new positions string via main function and
- `[3]` writes the array to column B.

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim v: v = getData(Sheet1, "A")                    ' << [1] assign data strings to variant array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        v(i, 1) = GetDigitPositions(v(i, 1))           ' << [2] main function finds positions 1..5
    Next i
    'write results                                     '    [3] write results
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(v), 1) = v

End Sub
```

**Main function `GetDigitPositions()`**

The function logic is based on the rarely known possibility of `Application.Match()` to return an entire set of position findings by passing two arrays thus avoiding loops:

```
Dim pos: pos = Application.Match(digits, data, 0)
```

**Note** that matching a digit which isn't available in data results in a not available error 2042.

As due to OP the digits 1..4 are always present in the data set, it suffices to execute a check via `If IsError(pos(5)) Then ...`

```
Function GetDigitPositions(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim data: data = Split(s, ",")                     ' e.g. 4|1|2|3  (without digit 5)
    Dim digits: digits = Split("1,2,3,4,5", ",")
    Dim pos: pos = Application.Match(digits, data, 0)
    If IsError(pos(5)) Then ReDim Preserve pos(1 To 4)
    GetDigitPositions = Join(pos, ",")                 ' e.g. "2,3,4,1" 
End Function
```

*Help function `getData()`*

```
Function getData(ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col = "A", Optional ByVal StartRow& = 2) As Variant()
    ' Purpose: assign column data to variant array
    If IsNumeric(col) Then col = Split(ws.Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    getData = ws.Range(col & StartRow & ":" & col & LastRow).Value2
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and well explained answer.

Comment: Nice. Voted up. I am asking myself if not possible to replace `digits = Split("1,2,3,4,5", ",")` with some Evaluate rows solution, even if I remember well, `digits = Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(data) + 1 & ")")` will return a 2D array. Not complicated to slice it on its unique column, but the array will be 1 based and I don't think that `Match` array will return something feasible. I am not sure that making `Data` also 1 based will solve the problem. Just for the sake of finding nicer alternatives... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru - always appreciate your feedback; I will need some time to think about a systematic answer as this week reveals to get stressful :-)

Comment: I am very busy, too. I will also try it, probably the day after tomorrow, if you will not solve it in the meantime :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this great `Application.Match` feature. I almost missed it.

Comment: @FaneDuru - 1) Yes, a flexible evaluation is possible, but needs some additions regarding not only the dimension. 2) `Match` accepts 0-based arrays, only the result will be 1-based in any case. -  Will be writing  a separate answer in response to your valuable feedback in order not to overcharge the above post

Comment: @FaneDuru - posted my promised overview as separate answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Please, test the next function. I hope I finally understood what you mean:

```
Function DigitsPos(strInit As String) As String
 Dim arr, arrFin, i As Long, matchN As Long, k As Long

 arr = Split(strInit, ",")
 ReDim arrFin(UBound(arr))
 For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    matchN = WorksheetFunction.Match(CStr(i + 1), arr, 0)
    arrFin(k) = matchN: k = k + 1
 Next i
 DigitsPos = Join(arrFin, ",")
End Function
```

It can be tested in this way:

```
Sub testDitigsPos()
 Dim x As String
 x = "4,1,2,3"
 Debug.Print DigitsPos(x)
End Sub
```

Or use the next code to solve your question in the worksheet:

```
Sub TestDigPosEvaluate()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
 lastR = sh.range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 For i = 2 To lastR
    sh.range("B" & i).Value = DigitsPos(sh.range("A" & i).Value)
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it does exactly that i would like to do with the data.The function also works well.

Comment: #Hunga; Glad I could help! But, we here when somebody spends some time and solve our problem, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code works. You received many answers and **I am not talking about mine**! Please, evaluate them and check the one looking better for your scope.

Answer (score 2):

### Match vs Loop

- It is assumed that the `OldTxt` array will always contain the numbers from `1` to `UBound(OldTxt) + 1`.
- The 2nd, the Match solution, should be more efficient.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub convertLoop()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim OldTxt As Variant
        Dim NewTxt As Variant
        Dim NewContent As String
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        Dim k As Long
        
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            OldTxt = Split(.Cells(i, 1), ",")
            ReDim NewTxt(0 To UBound(OldTxt))
            For j = 1 To UBound(OldTxt) + 1
                For k = 0 To UBound(OldTxt)
                    If CLng(OldTxt(k)) = j Then
                        NewTxt(j - 1) = CStr(k + 1)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k
            Next j
            NewContent = Join(NewTxt, ",")
            .Cells(i, 2) = NewContent
        Next i
    
    End With

End Sub

Sub convertMatch()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim OldTxt As Variant
        Dim NewTxt As Variant
        Dim NewContent As String
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            OldTxt = Split(.Cells(i, 1), ",")
            ReDim NewTxt(0 To UBound(OldTxt))
            For j = 0 To UBound(OldTxt)
                NewTxt(j) = CStr(Application.Match(CStr(j + 1), OldTxt, 0))
            Next j
            NewContent = Join(NewTxt, ",")
            .Cells(i, 2) = NewContent
        Next i
    
    End With

End Sub
```

To increase efficiency, you can copy the column range to an array and modify the array in memory and when done, copy it to the worksheet.

```
Sub convertMatchTurbo()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const srcCol As Long = 1
    Const dstCol As Long = 2
    ' Calculate Column Offset.
    Dim ColumnOffset As Long
    ColumnOffset = dstCol - srcCol
    ' Define Source Column Range.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, srcCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Columns(srcCol) _
          .Resize(LastRow - FirstRow + 1).Offset(FirstRow - 1)
    End With
    ' Write values from Source Column Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = rng.Value
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim OldTxt As Variant
    Dim NewTxt As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    ' Write resulting values to Data Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        OldTxt = Split(Data(i, 1), ",")
        ReDim NewTxt(0 To UBound(OldTxt))
        For j = 0 To UBound(OldTxt)
            NewTxt(j) = CStr(Application.Match(CStr(j + 1), OldTxt, 0))
        Next j
        Data(i, 1) = Join(NewTxt, ",")
    Next i
    ' Write values from Data Array to Destination Column Range.
    rng.Offset(, ColumnOffset).Value = Data

End Sub
```

With a few changes you can create a function to return the resulting array...

```
Function CMT( _
    aWorksheet As Worksheet, _
    Optional ByVal FirstRowNumber As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal SourceColumnNumber As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal DestinationColumnnumber As Long = 1) _
As Variant

    ' Calculate Column Offset.
    Dim ColumnOffset As Long
    ColumnOffset = DestinationColumnnumber - SourceColumnNumber
    ' Define Source Column Range.
    With aWorksheet
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, SourceColumnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Columns(SourceColumnNumber) _
          .Resize(LastRow - FirstRowNumber + 1).Offset(FirstRowNumber - 1)
    End With
    ' Write values from Source Column Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = rng.Value
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim OldTxt As Variant
    Dim NewTxt As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    ' Write resulting values to Data Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        OldTxt = Split(Data(i, 1), ",")
        ReDim NewTxt(0 To UBound(OldTxt))
        For j = 0 To UBound(OldTxt)
            NewTxt(j) = CStr(Application.Match(CStr(j + 1), OldTxt, 0))
        Next j
        Data(i, 1) = Join(NewTxt, ",")
    Next i
    ' Write result.
    CMT = Data

End Function
```

... and use it like this:

```
Sub TestCMT()
    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const srcCol As Long = 1
    Const dstCol As Long = 2
    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' Define Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = CMT(ws, FirstRow, srcCol, dstCol)
    ' Write values from Data Array to Destination Column Range.
    ws.Cells(FirstRow, dstCol).Resize(UBound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It needs me more time to understand all of your lines. They are clear, but a bit complex for me at first sight :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Addendum to Approach without loops due to @FaneDuru 's comment**

**Intro**

I'm trying to respond to @FaneDuru's remarks in comment of 2020-11-23,
which might illustrate some additional, but helpful methodical aspects.

As I don't want to *overcharge* my original answer, I posted this addendum as separate answer. *Any feedback is welcome.*

**Q & A's**

> *"I am asking myself if not possible to replace `digits = Split("1,2,3,4,5", ",")`
> with some **Evaluate rows** solution, ..."*

Yes, such a flexible evaluation is possible, but needs some additions.

The crux of the matter is not primarily the array dimension or base,
but whether strings are being compared with strings.

Since the mentioned evaluation would return numerical values only,
this flexibilized digits evaluation must also include a sort of **string conversion**
to avoid a Error 13 Type Mismatch (see help function ►`getDigits()`); this can be done by:

```
Evaluate("row(1:" & 5 & ") & """"")       ' add vbNullstring to the rows set
```

You mentioned correctly

> *"...even if I remember well, `digits = Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(data) + 1 & ")")` will return a 2D array."*

Therefore you have to execute a simple `Transpose` on the `digits` array to make it *comparable* with the `data` array, i.e. redimension it to a "flat" array.

```
digits = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(data) + 1 & ") & """""))
```

> *"Not complicated to slice it on its unique column, but the array will be 1 based and I don't think that Match array will return something feasible.
> I am not sure that making Data also 1 based will solve the problem. "*

Having transposed `digits` as shown above, there's no need to "fiddle" around `data`, i.e. to modify the `data` array, too.

**Further pecularity of `Application.Match()`**

Apparently it accepts even **two different array bases** as arguments.
So you can pass the *1-based* `digits` array as 1st argument and the *0-based* `data` array as 2nd argument,
only the resulting array `pos` will be **1-based** in any case.

*Extra*

For testing purposes the `getDigits()` help function allows to choose between zero- and one-based results.

---

**Main function `GetDigitPositions()` using ►`getDigits()`**

The function logic is based on the rarely known possibility of `Application.Match()` to return an entire set of position findings by passing two arrays thus avoiding loops:

```
Dim pos: pos = Application.Match(digits, data, 0)
```

```
Function GetDigitPositions(ByVal s As String) As String
'Purpose: the relevant function with main logic to calculate resulting positions
    '[0] get data
    Dim data: data = Split(s, ",")                              ' zero based

    Dim digits                          ' zero|one-based possible
    '[1]>> ►getDigits()<< function instead of simple Split("1,2,3,4,5", ",")
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'a) get digits with an additional base change (argument ZeroBased:=True)
    'digits = getDigits(5, IsLongType:=False, ZeroBased:=True) ' zero based 
    'b) get one-based digits
    digits = getDigits(5, IsLongType:=False, ZeroBased:=False) ' one  based 
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '[2] Match allows different bases, but always results in a 1-based array
    Dim pos: pos = Application.Match(digits, data, 0)
    If IsError(pos(5)) Then ReDim Preserve pos(1 To 4)
    '[3] return results
    If FreeOfErr2042(pos) Then                  ' always true in this example
         GetDigitPositions = Join(pos, ",")
'    Else
'         Dim i As Long
'         For i = LBound(pos) To UBound(pos)
'            Debug.Print i, pos(i)
'         Next i
    End If
End Function
```

**New Help function ►`getDigits()`**

This function supplies a flexible way to create array items `1 to n`.
An optional argument allows to choose between `Long` data type or string items.
The last (optional) argument can be used to change between zero- and one-based results.

```
Function getDigits( _
                    ByVal n As Long, _
                    Optional ByVal IsLongType = True, _
                    Optional ZeroBased As Boolean = True)
    Dim digits
    If IsLongType Then
        digits = _
            Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(1:" & n & ")"))        ' one  based
    Else
        digits = _
            Application.Transpose(Evaluate("row(1:" & n & ") & """"")) ' one  based
    End If
'    'redim digits base from 1-based to 0-based
    If ZeroBased Then ReDim Preserve digits(0 To n-1)          ' make it zero based
    'return digits
    getDigits = digits
End Function
```

*Additional help function `FreeOfErr2042()`*

Though not needed to solve the original question, this function may be helpful allowing
to use the `Join()` function. Reason: a single error 2042 item would prevent a working `Join` action.
It's possible to check this as `Count()` *ignores* the error items.

```
Function FreeOfErr2042(arr) As Boolean
'Purpose: check if array includes Error 2042 items
'Note   : necessary to allow Join() function (if wanted)
    Dim totalItems As Long: totalItems = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1
    Dim validItems As Long: validItems = Application.Count(arr)
    If totalItems = validItems Then FreeOfErr2042 = True
End Function
```

**(For the sake of completeness)**

*Unchanged help function `getData()`*

```
Function getData(ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col = "A", Optional ByVal StartRow& = 2) As Variant()
    ' Purpose: assign column data to variant array
    If IsNumeric(col) Then col = Split(ws.Cells(1, col).Address, "$")(1)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    getData = ws.Range(col & StartRow & ":" & col & lastRow).Value2
End Function
```

**Unchanged Example call**

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim v: v = getData(Sheet1, "A")                    ' << [1] assign data strings to variant array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        v(i, 1) = GetDigitPositions(v(i, 1))           ' << [2] main function finds positions 1..5
    Next i
    'write results                                     '    [3] write results
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(v), 1) = v
End Sub
```

*tl;dr - if I'd have forgotten further aspects in this rough overview, feel free to ask :-)*

Comment: Maybe I haven't looked close enough, but you do know that `Application.Match` works with a 2D any-based array if any of the dimension's `UBound` is equal to its `LBound` (one column or one row)!? Applying this to the 'revelation', depending on the first argument, the result will be a one-based array: If first argument is 2D, then the result will be 2D (column).

Comment: Very nice and comprehensive approach! Voted it up. I also spent some time on the issue earlier and I reached to the same (basic conclusion): The trick is to evaluate rows as string! I also created a (short) similar function but, since `Application.Match` works on 2D arrays, too it looked (to me) simpler to make the `data` array 2D. Posting the function here will not be clear, I am afraid. I will also post an answer. A short one. Only the function and a test `Sub` to test it...

Comment: `If IsError(pos(5)) Then ReDim Preserve pos(1 To 4)` is not necessary, anymore. Now, the code works for any number of data array elements. If the first argument of `GetDigits` should be `Ubound(data) +1`... Anyhow all the theory behind the solution is excelent!

Comment: Of course Match works on 2d arrays, too - just forgot to mention, as not needed here. Appreciated your feedback :-)

Answer (score 2):

A variant of @T.M. function (replacing `digits = Split("1,2,3,4,5", ",")`) would be the next one. It is able to process a big number of comma separated elements:

```
Function GetDigitPositions_(s As String) As String 
    Dim data: data = Split(s, ",")
    
    Dim digits: digits = Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(data) + 1 & ") & """"")
    
    Dim pos: pos = Application.Transpose(Application.Match(digits, data, 0))
    GetDigitPositions_ = Join(pos, ",")
End Function
```

It can be tested using the next `Sub`:

```
Sub testDitigsPos()
 Dim x As String
 x = "4,1,2,5,6,3"

 Debug.Print GetDigitPositions_(x)
End Sub
```

Comment: I think it is enough to transpose only once: either `digits` or `pos`. No need to transpose `data`. Off course, you have to change to `UBound(data) + 1`. `Split` is always 0-based; it is not dependent on `Option Base`.

Comment: @VBasic2008: Yes, indeed. I tried a lot of variants usually based on the supposition that similarity of 0/1 based arrays should be the trick, that I stuck this idea to my brain. In a way that, even after I understood that the string variant of rows evaluation is the problem, I still kept the initial version... Even if I could understand it from T.M. complex answer... I will adapt it in this regards. Simpler means better on my taste, too. :-)

Comment: Fine addition; indeed, it's the string variant of rows evaluation :-)